# Insert a React component into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-component

I have a query about the best way to go about this. So i have a stateless component called `<Banner/>` which just displays an image and some text.

I then have an array of objects which generates a list of features on the homepage of my site. There's roughly 15 objects in this `listGroups` array so it renders 15 `<Group/>` components one after the other. The code for this is below

```
  {listGroups.map((group, i) => (group?.assets?.length > 0) && (
     <Group key={group.id} {...group} showTitle={i !== 0} large={i === 0} />
  ))}
```

I would like to insert my `<Banner/>` component into this list in a specific position, ideally after the first `<Group/>` is rendered. I can use `array.splice` and add the component into a specific position into the array but it isn't rendered on the page so I'm obviously missing something here.

The end result would be something like this

```
<Group/>
<Banner/>
<Group/>
<Group/>
<Group/>
and so on
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array of JSX.Elements e.g.

```
const arr: JSX.Elements[] = [];

listGroups.forEach((group, i) => {
  if(i == 1) arr.push(<Banner/>);
  // add your Groups
})
```

and you can render the `arr`.

Answer (score 1):

You have various ways to achieve this.

In React you can render array of elements inside JSX, just like any other variable. If you wish to render components based some data that comes from api you could as well map your data and pass data to component. "key" property is required in both cases so React knows when structure changes.

Live example on CodeSandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-grass-p90q9

```
const List = [
  <MyComponent key="one" text="im 1st!" />,
  <MyComponent key="two" text="im 2nd" />,
  <MyComponent key="three" text="im 3rd" />
];

const data = [
  { text: "1st string" },
  { text: "2st string" },
  { text: "3st string" }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>Render array</h3>
      {List}
      <h3>Map from data</h3>
      {data.map(({ text }) => (
        <MyComponent key={text} text={text} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this and let me know if this is what you want

### Sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-lalande-mx5oz

```
//Have taken limit as 10 for demo
export default function App() {
  function print() {
    let group = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
      group.push(<Group key={i} />);
    }
    group.splice(1, 0, <Banner/>);// adding Banner at 1st index
    return group;
  }
  return <div>{print()}</div>;
}
```